# Send an e-mail from textarea and textfield in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, send

I made a PHP script for sending an email with the content written in a textarea using the mail() function as an action in a form tag within an static HTML document, How can I do this on Rails 4? I saw a lot of gems out there but is pretty confusing.

Comment: You should try adding more to your question.  It has a better chance of getting looked at (and answered) if people can tell that you have tried to find a solution yourself and that you have put time into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony). It's pretty robust and easy to setup. Just add the Pony gem to your Gemfile and send mail right in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will look forward to it